# Redirect URL with with a query string dynamically on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a very large website which has thousands of inner pages that all have the same affiliate link except a query string at the end of the url.

All of the inner pages use the same page template and we need to disguise the affiliate url.

For example:

we want to redirect:

www.mywebsite.com/view/video?q=the+title+of+the+video

to

www.externalwebsite.com?affid=123456?q=the+title+of+the+video

So the only part of the url that will change on each page is the title of the video.

I know how I can do it for one page using:

```
Redirect 301 /view/video?q=the+title+of+the+video 
www.externalwebsite.com?affid=123456?q=the+title+of+the+video
```

But obviously I can't go through all 20000 pages and do this.

Is there a .htaccess rule I can write that will work dynamically across all pages?

Comment: Is `affid=123456` a static value OR it will change as per the title of the video?

Comment: This is a static value, the only thing thats different is the q=

Comment: Then Sumurai8's answer should work with `QSA` flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manipulate query strings in redirects, use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Use the following code in the .htaccess file in your document root, or add it to the appropriate place in your main config file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^view/video$ http://www.externalwebsite.com?affid=123456 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

The `[QSA]` flag will append the current query string to the new query string. The rest is straight-forward.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, but all this does is redirect it to the affiliate link without the appending video title query. The redirect should append the q=video+title to the affiliate link

Comment: the `[QSA]` flag on that rewrite rule stands for Query String Append; which means it _should_ append the whole query string to the redirect.  If this redirect doesn't seem to work, watch your chrome network traffic and navigate, see if the stripping of the query string happens with this htaccess rule or on the destination website (for example, it adds a slash to the end of the URL)